# Get internet requesting application android

Tags: android

Hi I want to make an app in which I m monitoring the internet traffic in android.is there a way I can find which application is accessing internet and control it

Comment: Are you talking about sniffing, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor Internet traffic using `TrafficStats`. Whether or not there will be per-app (actually, per-UID) statistics will vary by device.

You absolutely cannot "control it".